# Trying to get a small part of an HTML a class element

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've been using BeautifulSoup on and off for a few years, and I still get tripped up from time to time.  I put together this code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.dammit import EncodingDetector
import requests

resp = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/gainers")
http_encoding = resp.encoding if 'charset' in resp.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
html_encoding = EncodingDetector.find_declared_encoding(resp.content, is_html=True)
encoding = html_encoding or http_encoding
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, from_encoding=encoding)
myclass = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "Fw(600) C($linkColor)"})
myclass
```

That gives me this.

```
[<a class="Fw(600) C($linkColor)" data-reactid="79" href="/quote/TSNP?p=TSNP" title="Tesoro Enterprises, Inc.">TSNP</a>,
 <a class="Fw(600) C($linkColor)" data-reactid="105" href="/quote/FDVRF?p=FDVRF" title="Facedrive Inc.">FDVRF</a>,
 <a class="Fw(600) C($linkColor)" data-reactid="131" href="/quote/SKLZ?p=SKLZ" title="Skillz Inc.">SKLZ</a>,
 <a class="Fw(600) C($linkColor)" data-reactid="157" href="/quote/GOOS?p=GOOS" title="Canada Goose Holdings Inc.">GOOS</a>,
 <a class="Fw(600) C($linkColor)" data-reactid="183" href="/quote/WMS?p=WMS" title="Advanced Drainage Systems, Inc.">WMS</a>, etc., etc.
```

What I really want is the stock symbols: TSNP, FDVRF, SKLZ, GOOS, WMS, etc., etc.

How can I modify this code to get just the stock symbols?  I tried to use regex, but I've never been very proficient with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.text` attribute of the elements returned from the `.findAll()` method:

```
for e in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "Fw(600) C($linkColor)"}):
    print(e.text)
```

Output:

```
TSNP
FDVRF
SKLZ
GOOS
WMS
APPS
...
```

If you want them in a list, a simple list comprehension will do:

```
gainers = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "Fw(600) C($linkColor)"})
tickers = [e.text for e in gainers]
```

Output:

```
['TSNP', 'FDVRF', 'SKLZ', 'GOOS', 'WMS', 'APPS', 'TIGR', ...]
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Just what I was looking for!!  Thank you gmdev!!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!